# Org function to hide content

Tags: org-mode

Is there an org function or combination of such that will hide all content but keep the currently visible headings visible?  That is, something like `org-content` but which does not show currently invisible headings.

Comment: I don't use Org, but just looking at the *Org* menu-bar menu, submenu *Show/Hide* it seems like something like *Cycle Global Visibility* (`<backtab>`) might do what you want.

Comment: @Drew `org-cycle` does not help much since it also changes the visibility of the headings. OP: "...but which does not show currently invisible headings".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`outline-hide-body` hides all text that does not belong to a headline below the first headline.

> Is there an org function or combination of such that will hide all content but keep the currently visible headings visible?

If you do not have text before the first headline `outline-hide-body` does exactly what you want.

---

You can use the following function to hide or reveal the text before the first headline.

```el
(defun outline-hide-preamble (&optional show)
  "Hide preamble, i.e., text before the first header.
   Show the preamble with non-nil SHOW.
   Interactively, use prefix arg to reveal the preamble."
  (interactive "P")
  (save-excursion
    (org-with-wide-buffer
     (goto-char (point-min))
     (unless (looking-at outline-regexp)
       (outline-next-heading)
       (outline-flag-region (point-min) (1- (point)) (null show))))))
```

Comment: great, thanks!  but how do i get the preamble back?  (should it perhaps be preamble rather than prefix?)

Comment: @Toothrot `outline-show-all` really shows all inclusively the preamble. BTW I am open for suggestions. Changed prefix to preamble.

Comment: @Toothrot I have changed `outline-hide-preamble` such that it reveals the preamble if it is called with prefix arg.